# How to Drag and Drop Item (Use ImageView) from One GridView to another GridView in same layout in android?

Tags: android, image, gridview

How to possible for Drag and Drop image from one GridView to another GridView?

I am using only ImageView for one GridView.

TextView and ImageView using for second Gridview.

My screenshot is:

[image]

Image set using Piccaso (use Image path). Not download image from server, directly set path using Picasso and display image in GridView Item.

How to do it?

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DynamicGridview`. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/02/android-tip-making-draggable-gridview.html).